# Unity | AudioSource.mute не работает

Tags: c#, unity3d, unity3d-android

У меня есть функция (прикручена к нажатию кнопки), которая **должна включать/отключать весь звук** на сцене (ну и сохранять наличие/отсутствие звука в *PlayerPrefs*). Она **работает абсолютно на рандом**, хочет - только работает **mute = true**, хочет - только **mute = false** (это меняется при обновлении скрипта). Я никак не могу понять почему.

Функция: (MusicBtn - кнопка звука, нужна только для смены иконки)

```
// using System.Linq
public void OnOffMusic()
{
    if (PlayerPrefs.GetString("Music") == "off")
    {
        PlayerPrefs.SetString("Music", "on");            
        MusicBtn.image.sprite = MusicOn;
    }
    else
    {
        PlayerPrefs.SetString("Music", "off");
        MusicBtn.image.sprite = MusicOff;
    }

    FindObjectsOfType<AudioSource>().All(audio => audio.mute != audio.mute);
}
```

Кнопка:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

**!!! Сразу 5 оговорок:**

1. Я могу свободно в редакторе **в рантайм** поменять значение **mute** на нужное и всё работает.
2. Я пробовал писать **mute = false** и **mute = true** явно.
3. Я делал отладку и **FindObjectsOfType** правильно находит все аудио
4. Я пробовал использовать ожидание по примерам в интернете (класс **Extensions**)
5. В **Start()** я проверяю существование в PlayerPrefs "Music"

**Extensions:**

```
public static IEnumerator Mute(this AudioSource audioSource)
{
    yield return new WaitForSeconds(0.01f);
    audioSource.mute = true;
}

public static IEnumerator Unmute(this AudioSource audioSource)
{
    yield return new WaitForSeconds(0.01f);
    audioSource.mute = false;
}
```

**Start():**

```
if (PlayerPrefs.HasKey("Music"))
    {
        if (PlayerPrefs.GetString("Music") == "off")
        {
            FindObjectsOfType<AudioSource>().All(audio => audio.mute = true);

            MusicBtn.image.sprite = MusicOn;
        }
    }
    else
    {
        PlayerPrefs.SetString("Music", "on");
    }
```

**Что делать???**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вы написали расширяющий метод используя итератор, в качестве возвращаемого значения:

```
public static IEnumerator Mute(this AudioSource audioSource)
{
    yield return new WaitForSeconds(0.01f);
    audioSource.mute = true;
}
```

Поэтому при при вызове **audioSource.Mute()** у вас не запустится корутина, а просто вернётся итератор, который вам самостоятельно придётся "двигать", чтобы поток выполнения кода дошёл до вашего заветного

```
audioSource.mute = true;
```

Решением будет заменить **audioSource.Mute()** на

```
StartCoroutine(audioSource.Mute());
```

В принципе, если у вас уже всё так и написано и я несу очевидные вещи, то прошу прислать больше данных.

Так же советую проверить массив `FindObjectsOfType<AudioSource>()` на наличие в нём элементов.

Comment: Спасибо, сейчас попробую. А насчёт наличия элементов в Find я писал))

Comment: Спасибо большое, всё работает